# Streaming audio from a webpage

Tags: url, ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to stream audio from another webpage through mine, but i do not know how to find the url for each audio file located on a separate webpage. It would also be extremely helpful to do everything in bulk so instead of writing a separate line of code for each audio file, simply writing a few lines of code to upload links to 100 audio files, etc. I am also using Ruby on Rails for my webpage.

How do you find a file located on a separate webpage?

Does anyone know, if possible how, to upload file links in bulk?

Comment: Please review the [Pro Webmasters FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) and consider updating your post to include a question.

Comment: ok i made it a little more blatant

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the many web page debugging tools like the [Developer tools](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/browser-developer-tools-tips-tricks.html) within browsers (keyboard shortcut - F12) or Fiddler or Firefox add-on Firebug to view web page elements including name & location of any audio files.

In [IE9](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/ie9-developer-tools-network-tab) & [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network), you can get the URL of files from the Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of "Audio stream"? in most cases the "Tune in"/"Live stream" button is just a plain link to a playlist file (.asx, .m3u, ...), handled by the client's mp3 player. Just link to the playlist file and you're done.

Comment: for example if i wanted to play a certain track located on the home screen of a webpage that contained several tracks how would i stream just that one